# OptaPlanner background thread not terminating

Tags: java, jvm, optaplanner

We are running OP (v8.11.1.Final) inside a standalone Java application (so we can evaluate it), but have noticed that once the solver has completed and returned the solution, the JVM will not terminate. It appears that there is a background thread still kicking around once we have returned from the `main` method that is keeping the JVM alive. The only way to get around this is to perform a `System.exit()` which does not seem that nice a solution.

Here are the list of threads still active. I guess some of these are JVM management threads, but something is still running causing this issue.

[image]

Any ideas? If you need more info let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask what API you use to submit a problem to the OptaPlanner? Is it the `Solver` or the `SolverManager` API?
Have you by any chance configured [multi-threaded solving](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#multithreadedIncrementalSolving)?

Comment: @RadovanSynek I am using `SolverManager.solveAndListen()`, and have not touched the multi-threading config.

Comment: @RadovanSynek Thanks for the pointer, I have just tried `solverConfig.setMoveThreadCount(SolverConfig.MOVE_THREAD_COUNT_NONE);` and that has fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you reproduce this every time? I'd love to get a reproducer. Even with moveThreadCount != NONE, it should clean up all thread pools after solving.

Comment: Both SolverManager starts a threadpool and `moveThreadCount != NONE` starts one too. Both give it a proper name. I wonder what that `pool-1-thread-1` is. Can you do a full thread dump and paste that?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Embarrassingly in fact didn't work, because I forgot to take out the `System.exit`! I think you are right, the `pool-1-thread-1` is the culprit. I will try and thread dump and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `SolverManager.close()` when you're done using it.
In Quarkus and Spring Boot, this happens automatically.

Or better yet, use it in an ARM block:

```
try (SolverManager<...> solverManager : SolverManager.create(...)) {
    ...
}
```

The SolverManager is a wrapper around a ThreadPool. And just like a ThreadPool needs to be explicitly closed, so does the SolverManager (so it can close its internal ThreadPool).

Comment: Retested (with no system exits this time!) and can confirm the `close` method call does shutdown the thread pool.